# how to roll out my own, simple user authentication 'database' for different services

Tags: django, apache, authentication, wiki

I'm currently using the following (web) applications that all need a username / password:

- apache2
- django
- dokuwiki
- bugzilla
- NIS

The problem I have is, that I currently need separate usernames / passwords for each of them formerly mentioned apps. I looked into unifying everything by using OpenLDAP, but for my 5 user setup this is an overkill. 
Is there a simple way of having something like a text file, which contains all usernames & passwords and that can be used for all above mentioned apps? Or do I have to use a 'real' big authentication system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is worth setting up those five systems for five users, it is probably worth the extra step of adding in LDAP.

Maybe you could do something at the Apache level as an alternative.